# How to calculate the standard error of a proportion estimate under misclassification?

Tags: inference, standard-error, discrete-data, measurement-error, error-propagation

Let's take a sample of size n from an infinite population. The population comes in three kinds ('red', 'black' and 'blue') and we want to know the proportions of each kind. For 'red' we would have $p = n_{red}/n$, with a
standard error $\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$.

What if now the operations within the sample had an associated error due to resolution issues?

For example, when computing p in the sample the operation gives a result with an error: $p = p' \pm \epsilon$ (due to computational limitation). This error is due to the fact that $n_{red}$ is extremely large and we truncate to have less significant digits, so $\epsilon = \epsilon_{red} / n$.

When $\epsilon= 0$, I understand that $p_{population} = p' \pm \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$, but what if $\epsilon >0$? How do I find $\delta$ such that $p_{population} = p' \pm  \delta$?

EDIT:

I think I came up with an answer. If we have $p = p' \pm \delta_p$, then this error would propagate as $\frac{d}{dp}\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}\vert _{p'} * \delta_p \equiv \delta$. Is that true?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're asking for the standard error of? The estimator $\frac{n_\mathrm{red}}{n} + \epsilon$, where epsilon is independently & uniformly distributed between -0.000001 & 0.000001? (Might help to explain why exactly you're introducing this extra random variable.)

Comment: Or are you saying that $n_{red}$ may not be the true number of red balls in the sample, but has a counting error associated with it? In the sense that the true number of red balls in the sample may be $m_{red}$ but due to resolution issues we decide it is instead $n_{red}$?

Comment: Yes, either there is a counting error or an error in $n_red/n$. $\epsilon$ represents the range of this error. I edited the post to make it clearer.

Comment: I think the question can be most easily answered in terms of $p'=m/n$ where $m=n_r+j$. You need to assume a distribution for the error $j$ and then derive the resulting standard error of $p'$. If you have independent repeated samples, it may be even possible to estimate the error distribution (of $j$). Otherwise all conclusions are based on assumptions about $j$.

Comment: (1) Is the error a function of the population proportion? Is it independent of the no. red balls observed in the sample? You need to specify its distribution, not just its range. (2) You seem to be conflating different types of error: "computational limitations" in the question (which would be deterministic, surely),  "counting errors" in the comment. What's actually being observed?

Comment: I edited the post to clarify it. The counting is correct but the numbers are too big to perform operations, so they are rounded. I guess they could be catalogued as counting errors then? In any case, this error is not independent of the number of red balls, in fact it only depends on its magnitude.

Comment: @tomka: Rather different distribution families would be appropriate, I think, depending on whether you're allowing for *miscounting* or *misidentifying*.

Comment: @guest: Then the error should depend deterministically on the no.red balls & on the sample size. Are you concerned with analysing results reported fairly crudely (e.g p=0.33, n=10), or with the limitations of floating-point operations?

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I'm not sure I understand your question. If we are keeping only the first $k$ significative digits and $n_red$ ~ $10^{15}$, then $\delta_{red} = 10^11$ and $\delta_{p} = 10^{11} / n$, so it also depends on $k$.

Comment: I think I know how to answer my question now. If we have $p = p' \pm \delta_p$, then this error would propagate as $\frac{d}{dp} \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}} * \delta_p$, and the total error would be $\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$ plus that propagation. Is that right?

Comment: Unless you are rounding to zero or one significant figure, considering the error it introduces in your estimate of standard error is of no consequence.  Remember: this already is an *estimate* of the standard error and is uncertain to begin with.  It looks like you are counting the fleas on an elephant's back when you are estimating the elephant's size.

Comment: What I was getting at is that the count of red balls rounded to the nearest hundred, say, isn't usefully modelled as a source of random variation in addition to that arising from sampling. It's a many-to-one function of the true count; a new test statistic whose distribution is fully known given any postulated proportion of red balls in the population: sufficient therefore for - exact - inference about that proportion.